# Мобильный способ оплаты

Tags: mobile, платежи

Кто делал на сайте мобильный способ оплаты? Может, общался с какими-то банками, которые предоставляли такую возможность. Или сервисы, может быть.

Comment: SMS-Online (https://ru.sms-online.com/) ничего такие.

Comment: А электронные деньги не нравятся? Робокасса, например.

Comment: Можно прикрутить по-отдельности и webmoney и yandex.деньги.

Comment: http://avisosms.ru/ вот вроде тоже ничего такие.

Comment: Помимо аггрегаторов можно и прямо с операторами мобильной связи попробовать связаться, но это вроде как дорого и больно.

Comment: Я списывался с опараторами, с их разработчиками. Они нечего не говорят. Только посылают на сторонние ссылки где нечего нет. Или говрят обращаться к самум гуглу.

Comment: А какую схему оплаты Вы предусматриваете? Просто обычно для работы с СМС-оплатой требуется, чтобы у вашего приложения был сервер и скрипт на сервере (защищённый), который мог бы дёргать СМС-провайдер при поступлении СМС на короткий номер и текстовый префикс, который Вы должны арендовать у провайдера.
После получения сообщения от СМС-провайдера ваш сервер должен уже что-то делать со статистикой ваших клиентов.

С какой целью Вас отсылают в гугл?

Comment: Я в гугл не отправляю, я нарушаю их правила публикаций. Поэтому я сам по себе. Я не знаю как проходит оплата по смс. Поэтому хотел тут узнать, может кто работал с этим и подскажет сервисы который мне помогут, с документацией.

Comment: А. Т.е. это будет неофициальное приложение с возможностью оплаты внутренних услуг по СМС. Тут просто открываются возможности для мошенничества. А СМС-провайдеров по каждому доказанному факту очень жестоко штрафуют. Скорее всего, большинство провайдеров не захочет связываться с подобными схемами. Стандартную схему работы СМС-провайдеров с сервисами и приложениями я изложил выше в комментариях.

Comment: То что вы привели в пример, не кто этим не занимается. Это просто рассылка спама.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, чем конкретно и кто не занимается? Что именно является рассылкой спама? Если приложение будет рассылать спам - СМС-шлюзам это так же не интересно, ибо за спам их тоже штрафуют.

Comment: ru.sms-online.com и avisosms.ru . Они ля маркетинга а не для приёма платежей.Я пишу про платежи, вы мне про другое.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, что Вы подразумеваете под "платежами"? Я под "платежами" понимаю такие ситуации: 1) когда пользователь посылает на короткий номер слово, со счёта списывются деньги, пользователь получает услугу в приложении. Или 2) пользователь заказывает услугу, сумма списывается с его мобильного счёта, пользователь получает услугу. Какой вид "платежей" нужен Вам?

Comment: Пользователь вводит номер телефона и логин в моём приложение. После, списываются средства с моб счёта, мне приходит ответ ( удачный или нет)

Comment: Пользователь может вводить произвольный номер телефона или номер телефона своего аппарата? Если произвольный номер - то человек А может ввести номер человека Б, которому придёт СМС с просьбой подтвердить списание с его мобильного счёта конкретной суммы. Если человек отвечает - сумма сисывается, мобильный аггрегатор сообщает вашему серверу (дёргает ваш скрипт на сервере) об (не)успешной тарификации. Далее Вы предпринимаете действия. Так же и со своим номером. Только в последнем случае можно его и не вводить, а сразу отправить префикс и логин на короткий номер. Далее всё по схеме (далее).

Comment: (продолжение) Далее аггрегатор получает на короткий номер префикс и логин. По префиксу и короткому номеру опознает ваш сервис. Оператор спишет средства по тарифу короткого номера. Аггрегатор получит подтверждение списания от оператора. Вы получите подтверждение и логин на свой скрипт от аггрегатора. Далее - Вы действуете согласно бизнес-логике вашего приложения (сервиса).

Comment: Оба вида платежей (и прямая отправка СМС и схема с подтверждением со стороны пользователя) доступны у представленных аггрегаторов.

Comment: они много хотят за такую возможность, мне нужен сервис который просто даёт мне код и берёт свой %

Comment: Я надеюсь, что когда Вам повезёт найти столь щедрое предложение, Вы поделитесь столь замечательной находкой с сообществом ruSO. Желаю Вам успехов во всех начинаниях!

Answer (score 3):

[SMS-Online](http://ru.sms-online.com) ничего такие.

А электронные деньги не нравятся? [Робокасса](http://robokassa.ru/ru/), например.

Можно прикрутить по-отдельности и [webmoney](https://www.webmoney.ru/) и [yandex.деньги](https://money.yandex.ru/new).

[avisosms.ru](http://avisosms.ru) вот вроде тоже ничего такие.

Помимо аггрегаторов можно и прямо с операторами мобильной связи попробовать связаться, но это вроде как дорого и больно.

Обычно для работы с СМС-оплатой требуется, чтобы у вашего приложения был сервер и скрипт на сервере (защищённый), который мог бы дёргать СМС-провайдер при поступлении СМС на короткий номер и текстовый префикс, который Вы должны арендовать у провайдера. После получения сообщения от СМС-провайдера ваш сервер должен уже что-то делать со статистикой ваших клиентов.